# django cms and zinnia skeleton override

Tags: python, django, overriding, django-cms, zinnia

I am trying to connect zinnia to django-cms 3.0

I have launched zinnia and it works just fine. Now I am trying to start changing styles. More specifically `templates/zinnia/skeleton.html` override.

Once I add template to override original template - url reverse starts on failing.

```
NoReverseMatch at /en-us/blog/
Reverse for 'entry_archive_index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

All of the urls use namespace as in `{% url 'zinnia:entry_archive_index' %}` and yet reverse in shell also just fails.

What else could be done to debug it? Maybe it's because of localization?

I have urls config:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^blog/', include('zinnia.urls', namespace='zinnia')),
    url(r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
    url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns(
        '',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
        url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
    ) + urlpatterns
```

Settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.comments',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'my_main_django_cms_app',
    'cms',
    'mptt',
    'menus',
    'south',
    'sekizai',
    'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
    'djangocms_picture',
    'djangocms_inherit',
    'djangocms_googlemap',
    'cmsplugin_contact',

    'tinymce',
    'tagging',
    'zinnia_threaded_comments',
    'zinnia',
    'cmsplugin_zinnia',
)
```

And my_main_django_cms_app structure is

```
.
├── cms_plugins.py
├── forms.py
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── models.py
├── settings.py
├── static
├── templates
│   ├── base.html
│   ├── home.html
│   └── zinnia
│       └── skeleton.html
├── urls.py
├── wsgi.py
```

And my versions:

```
Django==1.6.5
Pillow==2.4.0
South==0.8.4
argparse==1.2.1
beautifulsoup4==4.3.2
cmsplugin-contact==1.0.0
cmsplugin-zinnia==0.6
django-app-namespace-template-loader==0.1
django-blog-zinnia==0.14.1
django-classy-tags==0.5.1
django-cms==3.0
django-mptt==0.6.0
django-reversion==1.8.1
django-sekizai==0.7
django-tagging==0.3.2
django-tinymce==1.5.2
django-xmlrpc==0.1.5
djangocms-admin-style==0.2.2
djangocms-googlemap==0.0.5
djangocms-inherit==0.0.1
djangocms-picture==0.0.2
djangocms-text-ckeditor==2.1.6
gevent==1.0.1
greenlet==0.4.2
gunicorn==19.0.0
my_main_django_cms_app==0.1
html5lib==1.0b3
ipdb==0.8
ipython==2.1.0
psycopg2==2.5
pyparsing==2.0.2
pytz==2014.4
six==1.7.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
zinnia-threaded-comments==0.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been trying to integrate zinnia into django cms for a few days, and here's my experience, which gets me to the point where I can use my own django cms template for zinnia, but I'm still not getting the menus provided with `cmsplugin_zinnia` to work.

Compared to your setup, I've made the following changes:

- Deleted `zinnia` namespace, so `url(r'^blog/', include('zinnia.urls', namespace='zinnia'))` becomes `url(r'^blog/', include('zinnia.urls'))`.
- Added `app_name = 'zinnia'` to `cmsplugin_zinnia.cmsapp.ZinniaApphook`
- Moved `cms` after `zinnia` and before `cmsplugin_zinnia` from `settings.py` in  [demo_cmsplugin_zinnia](https://github.com/Fantomas42/cmsplugin-zinnia/blob/develop/demo_cmsplugin_zinnia/settings.py)

With this, I can select `Zinnia Weblog` as `Application` under `Advanced Settings` for a new Django CMS page, and give it a unique `Application Instance Name` as suggested in the [Django CMS docs.](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending_cms/app_integration.html#attaching-an-application-multiple-times) The name of the page or its url/slug field don't matter.

From here I can come up with my own `skeleton.html` that makes no reference to `zinnia` whatsoever, and have `zinnia.base.html` extend my new skeleton template.

However, at this point the [cmsplugin_zinnia docs](https://github.com/Fantomas42/cmsplugin-zinnia#tips-for-using-the-apphook) suggest:

- 'Once the apphook is registered, you can remove the inclusion of `zinnia.urls` in `urls.py` and then restart the server to see it in full effect.',

but instead I get a `NoReverseMatch at /name_of_my_blog_app/` exception, which only disappears if I include the `zinnia.urls` as above without `namespace`.

As a few weeks have passed since your original post, you may have resolved this by now.  If not, I hope this points you into the right direction. In case you ran into the same issues (`EntryMenu not loaded`) at some point and were able to resolve, please let me know.

Comment: Could you explain this step ```Added app_name = 'zinnia' to cmsplugin_zinnia.cmsapp.ZinniaApphook```?

Comment: Sure. After installation of `cmsplugin_zinnia`, go to `cms_app.py` in the main folder: https://github.com/Fantomas42/cmsplugin-zinnia/blob/develop/cmsplugin_zinnia/cms_app.py. There, you add the line `app_name= 'zinnia'` add the bottom of: `class ZinniaApphook(CMSApp)`. This is about namespacing apps vs. instances as explained here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces Sorry but the comment fields are not so great for pasting code. Let me know if you'd like me to sent the code separately.

Answer (score 0):

By using dev version for django-blog-zinnia, I see 'EntryMenu not loaded' no more. All menus related errors are gone now. As my understanding goes, this is due to inherent namespace issue in zinnia. Fantomas42 looks covering it in development version.

It has been tracked on https://github.com/django-blog-zinnia/cmsplugin-zinnia/issues/29